# auto-finding necessary but missing namespaces in C# using mono or vim on unix?

Tags: c#, unix, vim, ubuntu, mono

I am wondering if there is any plug-in or API that will automatically find what are the missing namespaces in my C# code developed in mono and vim on Ubuntu.

Thanks!!

Comment: would you have known set of references? I might wip something up if you let me know in what form you can provide the referenced assemblies

Answer (score 2):

In case of namespaces just click on unknown symbol (like Dictionary) with right mouse button and select Resolve > Using, it will add needed using.